# ValueError: Invalid field u'field' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'field', u'in', [59]) on object (ctx: )>" - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have these methods:

```
@api.depends('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
def _get_products(self):
    isbn = self.env['product.product']
    for prodtmpl in self.order_lines: 
        isbn |= prodtmpl.isbn
    return isbn

@api.model
def _get_act_window_dict(self, name):
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    result = mod_obj.xmlid_to_object(name)
    if not result:
        result = {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'stock.quant',
            'name': 'Stock On Hand',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        }
    else:
        result = result[0].read()[0]
    return result

@api.multi
def action_open_isbn(self):
    isbn = self._get_products()
    result = self._get_act_window_dict('stock.product_open_quants')
    result['domain'] = "[('isbn','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, isbn.ids)) + "])]"
    result['context'] = "{'search_default_locationgroup': 1, 'search_default_internal_loc': 1}"
    return result
```

On method `get_act_window_dict` it should return products on quants, like on Qty On Hand from `product.template`

But it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\stock\stock.py", line 331, in read_group
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 2082, in read_group
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4498, in _where_calc
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 662, in __init__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\osv\expression.py", line 830, in parse
ValueError: Invalid field u'isbn' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: (u'isbn', u'in', [59]) on stock_quant (ctx: )>"
```

I've tried doing this:

```
@api.model
def _get_act_window_dict(self, name):
    mod_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    result = mod_obj.xmlid_to_object(name)
    if not result:
        result = {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'stock.quant',
            'name': 'Stock On Hand',
            'isbn': 'product_id',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        }
    else:
        result = result[0].read()[0]
    return result
```

Adding `isbn` to the dict result as `product_id` but same result.

So, any ideas?

PS: This is `isbn` field on my class:

```
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
```

Of course it doesn't exist as `isbn` on `stock.quant` but it's a Many2one to `product` so it should pass somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
result['domain'] = "[('isbn','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, isbn.ids)) + "])]"
```

should be:

```
result['domain'] = "[('product_id','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, isbn.ids)) + "])]"
```

No field isbn in stock.quant. Since isbn is object product.product, I think it's just the same with product_id of stock.quant

Comment: Hey, Thank You very much